# Handle exception in Scheme script-fu

Tags: scheme, gimp, script-fu

I wrote a script for Gimp (script-fu !) in Scheme.

The script calls for the really awesome tool "resynthesizer", at some point.

`(python-fu-heal-selection 1 image drawable 10 0 0)`

Now, the probleme is that the user has to have installed Resynthesizer before.
If not, he will see a nasty error message like

> Error: eval: unbound variable: python-fu-heal-selection

What I'd like to do, is handle this exception more nicely, so the user can know what is wrong.

Something like :

```
try
    (python-fu-heal-selection 1 image drawable 10 0 0)
catch/except/handle exception eval, or something
    (gimp-message "You have to install Resynthesizer, see the tutorial")
```

But in Scheme.
I did my research, but... handling excptions in Scheme / script-fu is not very documented...

Thanks !

Comment: Do you use `eval` in your code?

Comment: Why are you doing that in script-fu... In python, you would just check `if 'python-fu_heal_selection' in dir(pdb)` (you can also catch exceptions...).

Comment: `eval` is the type of the error. The call for the function python-fu-heal-selection fails, because Heal selection is a part of Resynthesizer

Comment: I'm doing that in script-fu because I'm modifyng an existent script, it wasn't my choice.

Answer (score 1):

GIMP uses TinyScheme and according to [the documentation](http://tinyscheme.sourceforge.net/tinyscm.txt) `catch` syntax will catch all errors thrown. What you are looking for is somthing like this:

```
(catch (gimp-message "You have to install Resynthesizer, see the tutorial")
  (python-fu-heal-selection 1 image drawable 10 0 0))
```

This assumes that missing Resynthesizer is the sole cause of any errors.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll try that.
Catching all the exceptions like that is not perfect, but I'll see...